# Javascript incorrect display problem with for-loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, emoji

I'm new to `JavaScript`. Now I'm trying to write code that displays hearts based on numbers. Everything came out looking good. But there are some that are displayed incorrectly, namely the number 500. It is displayed as  But 600 it is displayed as  And it happened to 5000 and 6000 too, I can't find a solution right now.

**The Code:**

```js
function numbertoheart(r) {
  if (r <= 0) return "";
  for (var o = "", f = 0; f < Math.floor(r / 100000); f++) o += "";
  for (var $ = r % 100000, f = 0; f < Math.floor($ / 50000); f++) o += "";
  for (var $ = r % 50000, f = 0; f < Math.floor($ / 10000); f++) o += "";
  for (var $ = r % 10000, f = 0; f < Math.floor($ / 5000); f++) o += "";
  for (var $ = r % 5000, f = 0; f < Math.floor($ / 2000); f++) o += "❣";
  for (var $ = r % 2000, f = 0; f < Math.floor($ / 1000); f++) o += "";
  for (var $ = r % 1000, f = 0; f < Math.floor($ / 500); f++) o += "";
  for (var $ = r % 500, f = 0; f < Math.floor($ / 200); f++) o += "";
  for (var $ = r % 200, f = 0; f < Math.floor($ / 100); f++) o += "";
  for (var $ = r % 100, f = 0; f < Math.floor($ / 50); f++) o += "";
  for (var $ = r % 50, f = 0; f < Math.floor($ / 10); f++) o += "";
  for (var $ = r % 10, f = 0; f < Math.floor($ / 5); f++) o += "";
  for (var $ = r % 5, f = 0; f < $; f++) o += "❤";
  return o
}

console.log(numbertoheart(500));
console.log(numbertoheart(600));
console.log(numbertoheart(5000));
console.log(numbertoheart(6000));
```

Thank you in advance.

I want it to display correctly. It is similar to the rank system based on the number of points.

Comment: Please edit your question and include ALL relevant code (HTML/CSS) so that we may reproduce your issue. Also, please clarify what is supposed to happen as a result of your code running.

Comment: Also, this many loops, one after the other is a ["code smell"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell#:~:text=In%20computer%20programming%2C%20a%20code,%2C%20developer%2C%20and%20development%20methodology.). Are you sure you don't just want to use [`String.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Comment: Additionally `r % (any non-zero number that ends with 0)` will equal `0` so only the last (`r % 5` ) will work properly.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I apologize for the begining's mistake. I will follow everyone's suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The comments and previous answers said a lot already. Maybe this snippet can also be helpful in suggesting another (non-repetitive) way of solving the problem?

```js
function hearts(r) {
  return [[100000,""],[50000,""],[10000,""],[5000,""],
          [2000,"❣"],[1000,""],[500,""],[200,""],
          [100,""],[50,""],[10,""],[5,""],[1,"❤"]]
   .reduce(([v,s],[unit,heart])=>[v%unit,s+heart.repeat(Math.floor(v/unit))],[r,""])[1];
}

// tests:
[500,600,5000,6000,2586,100001].forEach(r=>console.log(r,hearts(r)))
```

At the centre of the operation is a `.reduce()` loop over an array of arrays. In each step of the reduce-loop the current sub-array is deconstructed into a `unit`(value) and a `heart` (string) associated with it. With `Math.floor(v/unit)` I calculate the number of occurrences of `unit` in `v` and at the end of each step in the reduce loop I return the updated array with the remainder of the value `v%unit` and the accumulated heart string `heart.repeat(Math.floor(v/unit))` in it.

Comment: This looks very easy to use. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that after you add some hearts to the result, you don't subtract their values from `r`.

For instance, `r % 1000` is `500`, so you display one . But `r % 200` is `100`, so you also display .

You should reduce `r` to the remainder of the value of that emoji after that loop. You can achieve that in your code be reusing `r` instead of using `$` in each loop.

```js
function numbertoheart(r) {
  if (r <= 0) return "";
  for (var o = "", f = 0; f < Math.floor(r / 100000); f++) o += "";
  for (r = r % 100000, f = 0; f < Math.floor(r / 50000); f++) o += "";
  for (r = r % 50000, f = 0; f < Math.floor(r / 10000); f++) o += "";
  for (r = r % 10000, f = 0; f < Math.floor(r / 5000); f++) o += "";
  for (r = r % 5000, f = 0; f < Math.floor(r / 2000); f++) o += "❣";
  for (r = r % 2000, f = 0; f < Math.floor(r / 1000); f++) o += "";
  for (r = r % 1000, f = 0; f < Math.floor(r / 500); f++) o += "";
  for (r = r % 500, f = 0; f < Math.floor(r / 200); f++) o += "";
  for (r = r % 200, f = 0; f < Math.floor(r / 100); f++) o += "";
  for (r = r % 100, f = 0; f < Math.floor(r / 50); f++) o += "";
  for (r = r % 50, f = 0; f < Math.floor(r / 10); f++) o += "";
  for (r = r % 10, f = 0; f < Math.floor(r / 5); f++) o += "";
  for (r = r % 5, f = 0; f < r; f++) o += "❤";
  return o
}

console.log(numbertoheart(500));
console.log(numbertoheart(600));
console.log(numbertoheart(5000));
console.log(numbertoheart(6000));
```

Comment: It cleared up my problem a lot. Thank you so much!